# dynamically added buttons (tooltips and text)

Tags: c#, html, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

If buttons are dynamically added in wpf from code behind how can you add tooltips to them or text to the actual button?

This is what you would do in windows forms but I dont think you can do it in wpf:

```
partial class Window1
{
    void button3Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, "My button1");
        MessageBox.Show("action 3");
    }
    void button2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("action 2");
    }
    void button1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("action 1");
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        populateButtons();
        //ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

        //// Set up the delays for the ToolTip.
        //toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
        //toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1000;
        //toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;
        //// Force the ToolTip text to be displayed whether or not the form is active.
        //toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;

    }

    public void populateButtons()
    {
        int xPos;
        int yPos;


        Random ranNum = new Random();
        foreach (var routedEventHandler in new RoutedEventHandler[] { button1Click, button2Click, button3Click })
        {

            Button foo = new Button();
            Style buttonStyle = Window.Resources["CurvedButton"] as Style;
            int sizeValue = 100;

            foo.Width = sizeValue;
            foo.Height = sizeValue;

            xPos = ranNum.Next(200);
            yPos = ranNum.Next(250);

            //canvas1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            //canvas1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            //canvas1.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);

            foo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            foo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            foo.Margin = new Thickness(xPos, yPos, 0, 0);
            foo.Style = buttonStyle;

            foo.Click += routedEventHandler;

            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

}

As for adding text im not sure?

Here is the xaml:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xml:lang="en-US"
    x:Class="DynamicButtons.Window1"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Dynamic Buttons"
    Width="840" Height="600" Icon="shape_group.png">
    <Window.Resources>   
            <Style x:Key="CurvedButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseMove1">
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="#7CE1DBDB"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1.66"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1.66"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeave1">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8000000" Value="1.78"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.8000000" Value="1.78"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="OnClick1">
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                        <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="#BFA0D1E2"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle RenderTransformOrigin="1,1" Fill="#3FFFFFFF" Stroke="{x:Null}" RadiusX="11" RadiusY="11" x:Name="rectangle">
                                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                                            <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnClick1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick1}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseLeave1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeave1}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"/>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseMove1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseMove1}"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#E1CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"/>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.484,0.543" StartPoint="0.478,0.009">
            <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>

        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas Height="282" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="343" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use the [Tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tooltip.aspx)-Property?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a `ToolTip` to the `ToolTip` property of the `Button` and set the `Content` property to the text you want to display:

```
ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
t.Content = "Something helpful";

Button b = new Button;
b.Content = "Hover over me";
b.ToolTip = t;
```

If you want to make the button show up apparently you have to add it to the panel it should belong to - which I assume is the canavs:

```
// add the button to the canvas
canvas1.Children.Add(b);
// set the position of the button on the canvas
Canvas.SetLeft(b, 20);
Canvas.SetTop(b, 20);
```

Comment: Would help if I had buttons to begin with. just doesnt show anything using this method.

Comment: `foo.Content = "Hover over me";` this works but sets them all rather than individually like I said they are set dynmaically

Comment: @KirstyWhite: I have added some sample code to show how to add the button to the canvas so it will show up. Not sure what exactly you mean by "sets them all". You create all the buttons you need (maybe in a loop) and for each button you set the content property to whetever text you like.

Comment: Hello chris, no I dont think you understand what my code does never mind pal.